# Can I blanket deny all websites from giving me desktop notifications in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, notifications

Every once in a while I find an interesting article, but nothing turns me off of a news site more than them asking "Hey, can we bug you every time we think we have something you may like?" via desktop notifications.

What's even worse is when I accidentally click "yes" and get bombarded with news articles until I turn it off.

Is there a way to blanket deny this permission?

Answer (score 4):

As per [this Google Chrome Help entry](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), there is a way to disable all notification requests in Google Chrome:

1. Enter `chrome://settings/content/notifications` in your address bar
2. Disable the `Ask before sending` property.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings -> Advanced -> Privacy and security`

Click `Content settings` and then click `Notifications`.

Turn off `Ask before sending` to block all the notifications.